# Packages have unmet dependencies error

Tags: release-juno, apt

whenever i try to install anything, i get that. Me and my dumb self also decided to uninstall appcenter, this is another problem im having, 
`sudo apt-get install appcenter`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 237-3ubuntu10.15)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: The error says the solution, please execute `sudo apt --fix-broken install` first and then install [tag:appcenter]. Let us know what you find.

Comment: have tried that, the output from sudo apt --fix-broken install is `dpkg: error processing package libpam-runtime (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-runtime
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please execute this series of commands,

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Above answer is grabbed from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716915/dpkg-error-processing-packages-cannot-complete-install-desktop-gui-from-termina).